# What is the safest OS to use Tor while being untraceable

Tags: windows, mac, linux, tor-install

I heard that *Microsoft Windows* and *Mac OS* were not safe, and that unix-like based OS like Ubuntu or Debian were better.

Is it true? If yes, why the 2 first are not recommendable ?

What is the safest (and easiest) linux OS to use in order to be safe and untraceable with Tor ?

Answer (score 1):

Windows and Mac are closed sourced and therefore code is not open to public review and that takes away the user trust. They are not designed with privacy in mind.

You should rather look at alternatives such as running a [Whonix](https://www.whonix.org/) or [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) based system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is it safe to use Whonix or Tails on a WIndows OS ?

Comment: Whonix runs inside a separate VBox. No data leak is possible even with root access. Tails is a LIVE disk. Should be used on a USB drive to completely bypass Windows.

Comment: I will give them a try thank you for your explanation! Just a quick question, is it necessary to use a VPN before launching them ?